# Override an attribute in chef resource

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I created a wrapper cookbook for the [redisio community cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/redisio) and I want to override `download_dir` attribute from `resources/install.rb`:

```
attribute :download_dir, :kind_of => String, :default => Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]
```

Because of `file_cache_path` it taking the path where chef-client is running (/var/chef/cache). The issue is that in `attributes/default.rb` (of the redisio cookbook), as there is only `install_dir` which is creating a bin in my specified folder like this:

```
node.override['redisio']['install_dir'] = '/redis-setup'  -> rediswrapper cookbook
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of including the [install recipe](https://github.com/brianbianco/redisio/blob/master/recipes/install.rb), you could just take the important parts and call the `redisio_install` provider yourself and supplying the `download_dir` option, e.g. using

```rb
include_recipe 'redisio::_install_prereqs'
include_recipe 'build-essential::default'

redis = node['redisio']
location = "#{redis['mirror']}/#{redis['base_name']}#{redis['version']}.#{redis['artifact_type']}"

redisio_install "redis-installation" do
  version redis['version'] if redis['version']
  download_url location
  safe_install redis['safe_install']
  install_dir redis['install_dir'] if redis['install_dir']
  download_dir "/tmp"
end
```